# In JavaScript, how do I detect whether or not the input contains letters?

Tags: javascript, character, letter

My code is below, it outputs what the user is typing in the text box. It should output an error message if the user puts anything other than a number. I'm confused as to how to do this, though. Quite frankly, I'd settle with it being able to detect whether or not the first letter of input is a B, but I can't quite figure that out either and the former option is preferred.

**HTML**

```
<label for="bannerID">Banner ID: B</label><input type="text" name="bannerID" id="bannerID" onkeyup="showBannerID()" value="" /><br /> 

<p id="bannerOutput"></p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function showBannerID() {

var textInput = document.getElementById('bannerID').value;

if (textInput.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById('bannerOutput').innerHTML = "<strong class=\"error\">Field can't be empty!</strong>";
}
else if (textInput.charAt(0) == "B") {
    document.getElementById('bannerOutput').innerHTML = "<strong class=\"error\">Please omit the B! It's not necessary.</strong>
}
else {
    document.getElementById('bannerOutput').innerHTML = "Your Banner ID is: <strong>B" + textInput + "</strong>.";
}
}
```

Comment: Your code contains a syntax error. Did you know that? (the quote at the else-if-B block is not closed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use isNaN() (Not a Number) as a condition.

isNaN(123) would give false, isNaN("hello") would give true.

Comment: Perfect! Now is there a way I could implement that, as well as implementing an else if for if they put in a B as the first letter?

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions to search for anything other than numbers:

```
if (/[^\d]/.test(textInput)) {
    /* error stuff */
}
```

Comment: I'll have to look this up, we haven't learned regular expressions yet.

Further question: is there a way to detect whether or not the first number they put in is a B, and output an error message if they do?

Comment: @Doug Your `charAt` test should work for that. Are not getting the results you expect?